# How to get a list of IPs in a LAN using NodeMcu?

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu, raspberrypi, iot, mqtt

I'm going to create an IoT system. I use a Raspberry Pi as a MQTT broker and as a webserver. Every day, the Pi gets a new IP address, so I need to find its new IP address via ESP8266 to use this information in my code. I know that I can use a fixed IP, but I don't want to, so it is better if I can find a solution.

Comment: What is the question you are asking?

Comment: Welcome to the Arduino stackexchange. Please be sure to take the tour, to know, how things are working here: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: You could use mDNS.

Comment: There was some problem in the libraries that i tried, i'm trying to solve it via Pinging now.

Comment: As @Gerben say use multicast DNS aka AVAHI, it is even supported on ESP's  ref.: https://tttapa.github.io/ESP8266/Chap08%20-%20mDNS.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all, if your Raspberry Pi acts as webserver and mqtt broker, in my opinion you should assign a fixed ip-address, either via configuration in the access point/router or via static ip.

However, if you insist on your approach you could do some hands-on method of pinging all addresses in your LAN-subnet and checking for the MAC-address of the respondents.
If the MAC-address matches to that of your Pi, you have found it.

I have not tested it myself, but this [library](https://github.com/bluemurder/esp8266-ping/blob/master/examples/Ping/Ping.ino) seems to have what you need for this purpose.
After finding a responsive ip-address via ping, it tries to resolve the corresponding MAC-address using the [etharp_find_addr](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/tools/sdk/lwip/src/netif/etharp.c) function.

This struct field is the reference to a 6 byte character array that you can use for comparing with the Raspberry Pi's MAC address:

```
response.DestMacAddress->addr
```

---

Update:
If you only want to find the IP address of the Raspberry Pi, using mDNS as suggested by @Majenko is the superior choice.
If you are looking for all devices in your LAN, as your title suggests, pinging makes more sense.

Comment: I had a Lib problem, now i fixed it and i really close to get the result. In the loop, i send all of the ip addresses that i want and the mac adresses are shown in 
    pinger.OnEnd([](const PingerResponse& response) 
function. I wrote a function for convert response.DestMacAddress->addr to String. 

    mac = mac2String(response.DestMacAddress->addr); I would like to have it on my setup function for create a list. But i can't. Could you please help me?

Comment: I am sorry, but I cannot follow your explanation. I guess it would be best, if you ask a separate question on Stack Overflow for this programming issue. Then you can layout all your code, your results/error messages and what you expect from the program. Then feel free to link to this question.

Answer (score 1):

You should use mDNS.  Install (if it isn't already) `avahi-daemon` on your Raspberry.

Then check out the ESP8266mDNS library and the examples it has. Especially the mDNS-SD_Extended example, which performs a query for a service on the network.

Comment: I need also some other devices' ips. That's why mDNS does't work.

Comment: Make those use mDNS as well, then. Either that or redefine your expectations and requirements and embrace the static IP address.